# Fourier coefficients of the product of two functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, inner-products

Given two functions $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, I have to prove that the Fourier coefficients of $fg$ are given by

$$\hat{fg}(n)=\sum_{k\in{Z}}\hat{f}(n-k)\hat{g}(k)$$

and that this series converges uniformly.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The series you wrote converges absolutely by Cauchy-Schwarz (and recall Parseval). Do you have any idea why this would converge to the desired coefficient? Just for fun, you could use [Carleson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem)...

Comment: Ok, i understand now the convergence of the series. But i can't see how to prove the equality...

Comment: My previous comment was completely wrong, sorry. Here is a safe way. Prove it for $f,g$ trigonometric polynomials.  Then use their $L^2$ density (that's Bessel, or Parseval), and the continuity of both sides of the formula on $L^2\times L^2$.

Comment: Can anyone detail this a bit more? I still can't see well how to prove it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz and Parseval:
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(n-k)||\hat{g}(k)|\leq (\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(n-k)|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{g}(k)|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|f\|_2\|g\|_2
$$
so the rhs converges absolutely. By Cauchy-Schwarz again, but in $L^2$, the pointwise product $fg$ is in $L^1$, so the lhs is well-defined.

Note that these are both bilinear forms on $L^2\times L^2$ bounded by $\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$. To prove that they coincide, it suffices to do it for a dense set. By Parseval, the trigonometric polynomials form such a set.

To verify this for the trigometric polynomials, it suffices to do it for $p(t)=e^{irt}$ and $q(t)=e^{ist}$ for any $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now
$$
(pq)(t)=e^{i(r+s)t}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \widehat{pq}(n)=\delta(n,r+s)
$$
and 
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{p}(n-k)\hat{q}(k)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\delta(n-k,r)\delta(k,s)=\delta(n-s,r)=\delta(n,r+s).
$$

**Note:** I realize I did it for $L^2([0,2\pi])$. To adapt this to $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, just replace $p$ and $q$ by $z^r$ and $z^s$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, julien. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Thank you. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To establish that the series on the right-hand side is convergent, you can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

To prove the convolution formula, it suffices to show that

$\sum_n\left(\sum_k\hat f(n-k)\hat g(k)\right)e^{inx} = f(x)g(x)$

for which it's handy to write $e^{inx} = e^{ikx}\cdot e^{i(n-k)x}$. Then you'll have to justify the interchange of a doubly-infinite sum, with whatever amount of rigor your instructor expects. I can give more details but it's more fun to do it yourself ;)

Comment: The point is that it is not true in general that the Fourier series of $f$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Comment: In that case you'd probably have to prove the formula for some nice set of functions and then appeal to density to extend the result of all of $L^2$.

Comment: My comment was completely wrong, actually...I deleted it.