# Function as a convolution product of other two

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

I need help with this:

I have to prove that a function $f\in L_{2}(T)$ can be expressed as $f=g*h$ (convolution product) for some functions $g,h\in L_{2}(T)$ if and only if $(\hat{f}(n))_{n}\in l_{1}(Z)$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: T is the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, it is,  Blumenthal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in L^2(T)$, where $T$ is the 1-torus, aka unit circle.

Assume that $f = g * h$ for $g,h \in L^2(T)$. Notice that $\hat{f} = \hat{g} \cdot \hat{h}$ elementwise on $\mathbb{Z}$ by the convolution theorem in this setting. Note $g,h \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. By the Holder Inequality,
$$
\|\hat{f}\|_{\ell^1}= \|\hat{g} \hat{h}\|_{\ell^1} \leq \|\hat{g}\|_{\ell^2} \|\hat{h}\|_{\ell^2} < \infty
$$

So much for the "easy" part. For the other direction, we basically want to define $\hat{g}$ and $\hat{h}$ by "hand". One such construction is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(n) &= \sqrt{|\hat{f}(n)|} \\
\hat{h}(n) &= \begin{cases} \frac{\hat{f}(n)}{|\hat{f}(n)|} \sqrt{|\hat{f}(n)|} & \hat{f}(n) \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align*}

We now have $\hat{f} = \hat{g} \cdot \hat{h}$ elementwise on $\mathbb{Z}$, and both $\hat{g}, \hat{h} \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ whenever $\hat{f} \in \ell^1$ (just look at how the norms are defined). Now recall that the fourier transform on $T$ is an isometry $L^2(T) \mapsto \ell^2(T)$, and so the inverse transforms of $\hat{g},\hat{h}$ are in $L^2(T)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Blumenthal!!
I have another question involving Fourier coefficients.
Could you help me with that too?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362845/fourier-coefficients-of-the-product-of-two-functions

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact a well known general fact, even for LCA (locally compact Abelian groups). A function is in the Fourier algebra (the set of all Fourier transforms of L1-functions, so we are living in the frequency domain, here Z) if and only if it is the convolution product of two L2-functions.

Pierre Eymard has done remarkable work on the Fourier Algebra A(G) even for non-commutative locally compact groups. Using C*-algebra arguments he was able to show that this is a linear space (not at all obvious) as well as an algebra in the pointwise sense.

P. Eymard: L'algèbre de Fourier d'un groupe localement compact
 Bull. Soc. Math. France, Vol.92 (1964) p.181-236.

Comment: This old question already has an accepted answer, at a very appropriate level. There's no point in answering in such abstraction.